# add icon on top of Font Awesome in button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've create something like that, but in my button i want something like - `<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>` in the right top.
HTML:

```
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm " > <i  class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-lg" style="color:green"></i><span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span></button>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-stack[data-count]:after{
  position:absolute;
  right:0%;
  top:1%;
  content: attr(data-count);
  font-size:30%;
  padding:.6em;
  border-radius:999px;
  line-height:.75em;
  color: white;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,.85);
  text-align:center;
  min-width:2em;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Here is my code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqZENw
Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `position: relative` to the button and `position: absolute` to the icon within.

Like this:

```
button {
  position: relative;
}

button i.fa.fa-clock-o {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```